# Loop counter not incrementing

Tags: c, arrays, loops

The below function `aquire_marks` is designed to take 5 user-inputed numbers, and store them in `marks`. When run, the for loop runs once as expected with `j=0`, and then as expected for `j=1`, but then `j` is never incremented to `2`, and stays at `1`, leaving the function in an infinite loop. If the loop is placed inside `main`, this problem does not happen, but I'd prefer to have it inside a separate function if that is possible. Any clue what is going on here?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void aquire_marks(char marks[], char names[][11]){ // 11 - max name length + 1
    char j, mark;

    for(j=0; j<5; j++){
        printf("Enter mark for %s: ", names[j]);
        scanf("%d", &mark);
    }
}

int main() {
    char names[5][11] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    char marks[5];

    aquire_marks(marks, names);
}
```

Comment: Why is j a `char` and then used as an index in a loop?

Comment: `scanf("%c", &mark);`? isn't that a `char`? or it should be `int`.

Comment: You passed `marks[]` but ignored it.

Comment: `%d` wants an `int`. You are passing a `char`, so `scanf` overwrite the `j` variable into stack...

Comment: I've just used char because I don't need my numbers to be any bigger than 128... Is that bad practice?

Comment: Yes: use the natural size `int` unless there is good reason not to.

Comment: I repeat: `char` is **1 byte variable**, `%d` wants an `int` variable (probably 4 bytes) ....

Comment: so would it not be more efficient (memory wise) to use a char?

Comment: Are you short of memory? But probably not anyway if variable storage is aligned, you'll just be wasting 3 bytes anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've declared `mark` as a `char`, but in the `scanf` call you're using the `d` conversion specifier, which expects its corresponding argument to have type `int *`, not `char *`.  Using the wrong conversion specifier results in undefined behavior.

I'm going to speculate that `mark` and `j` are adjacent in memory, and that in the process of reading an integer value for `mark` (which could anywhere from 2 to 4 bytes wide) the value of `j` is getting overwritten.

Is `mark` supposed to represent a numerical value (`90`, `75`, etc.)?  If so, change the type of `mark` from `char` to `int`.

If `mark` is supposed to represent a letter grade (`A`, `B`, etc.), then change the `scanf` call to

```
scanf( " %c", &mark ); // note leading whitespace
```

Comment: nah I chose char specifically as I only need numbers less than 128

Comment: @ACarter: Better to use `int` and do your own range checking, but okay.  If you want to read *numeric* values and store them in a `char` type, then use `%hhd` as the conversion specifier instead of `%d` so `scanf` will read the correct number of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing address of `1 byte` variable (`char`) to a function that will threat it as a `int` pointer.

If we assume that `int` is `4 bytes`, `scanf` overwrite `3 byte` of stack near to `mark` variable.

The first one is, presumably, `j`;

Answer (score 0):

I would change the declaration of j to an `int`.

```
char mark;

for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
    printf("Enter mark for %s: ", names[j]);
    scanf("%d", &mark);
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the real issue (or even mention it).